# Unable to create an object of type 'AppContext'. Npgsql + EFCore

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How to resolve my "HelloEFCore" .NET Core console app exception? I use Npgsql Entity Framework Core Provider (https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/)

> Unable to create an object of type 'AppContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

It occurs when I try to do initial migration

```
dotnet ef migrations add CreateDatabase
```

Code that I'm working with:

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppContext a = new AppContext("Server=127.0.0.1; port=5432; user_id=postgres; password=root; database=db; pooling=true");
    }
}
```

**Product.cs**

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
}
```

**Brand.cs**

```
public class Brand
{
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
}
```

**AppContext.cs**

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    public AppContext(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString ?? 
            throw new ArgumentException("connectionString is empty.");
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseNpgsql(_connectionString);
    }
}
```

**efstart.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.8" />
  <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="4.1.3"/>
  <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="3.1.3"/>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.4"/>
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Application compiles well. I use pgAdmin on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Please check my answer to the following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64493635/how-do-i-set-aspnetcore-environment-to-production/64494993#64494993

The solution should also work in your context, just adapt context name, database and path/filename to your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement IDesignTimeDbContextFactory interface to make your solution work without any problems.

```
public class AppContext Factory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory< AppContext>
{
    public AppContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppContext>();

        builder.UseNpgsql(connectionString);

        return new DataContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed a constructor as there: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#onconfiguring an works well, but I want rather it work with DI. Can you show full code implementing IDesignTimeDbContextFactory because it looks painful. I want to know how to inject connectionstring especially.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://blog.tonysneed.com/2018/12/20/idesigntimedbcontextfactory-and-dependency-injection-a-love-story/